# textarea post gets diffrent result with or without "\"?

Tags: php

textarea post gets diffrent result with or without "\"?

the same code runs in different pc , get the diffrent result

my systerm is xp , and I post textarea and print it , the result has "\" befror ' , but I run it in other guy's pc ,the result returns no "\". 
this defferent result cause that when I insert mysql , returns error when the sql has no "\"
why this happen ? how to fix ?

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
 ?>
</pre>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10">This is kate's book</textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

in my pc ,get:

```
this is kate\'s book
```

in others, get:

```
this is kate's book
```

---

add in htaccess is ok

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1
```

Comment: "this defferent result cause that when I insert mysql" sounds like you're not sanitising your inputs. Hackers will love you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here comes from the `magic_quotes_gpc` setting in your php.ini. You have to turn it off: this thing is pure evil (and deprecated). It "escapes" your data automagically.

However, you still want it escaped. The best way to do that is by using [PDO](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared requests.

Comment: any php function to set the magic_quotes_gpc on or off in php?

Comment: If you have access to the php.ini file, you can (and should) set it off there. If the code is running on your PC you're fine; if it's running on a mutualized hosting service you're out of luck. In that case, use ini_set at the beginning of your code. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 1):

Probably the php configurations are different between you and your friend computer. Try to use php function stripslashes.

```
$var = stripslashes($another_var);
```